# Magento 2 - Allow only one shipping address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

I have created provision for customer to be able to select a shipping address before login in. And I would like only that shipping address to appear and don't want customer to be able to change it to any other shipping address or add any new address.

I am not able to find from where the address collection is coming where I can write my code to restrict it returning only the previously selected address.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this by (just) configuring the settings in `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Multishipping Settings` and turn those off.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to have only one address displayed during checkout. And that address may not necessarily be the default address. So I would need to some logical modification from where Magento is fetching shipping address in checkout page

Comment: @Dharam - I also want to show only one address in checkout page. Did you find a solution.